# Validating understanding on parameterizations and related terminologies

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I am reading an interesting book on Differential geometry by Wolfgang Kuhnel. Considering that I am not trying to delve too deep into abstract math and am studying this subject for the sole purpose of having stronger mathematical tools and enhancing intuitive power for understanding higher level physics, I would like to ask for explanations of the following terminology and validation for whether my line of thought in the right direction.

I am currently reading a chapter on Local theory of surfaces. I have some basic knowledge on Point set topology and assume this has got a lot to do with Manifolds; which I imagine as complex looking surfaces that have a flat space like behavior if observed from close enough. The chapter starts off by defining a parameterized surface to be a function
$f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$
which I imagine as some function that takes in points from a 2D surface, say the (x,y) plane, and maps it onto a point in a higher/ambient space. Doing this for all points in some open set $U$ of the input surface results in a 2D surface embedded in 3D. I am assuming the domain $U$ is chosen to be open to help define topological properties of the mapped surface, but I am not too sure about that.

Everywhere in the book $f$ is defined to be an immersion if its Derivative is full rank. I assume that this means if we see $f$ as a transformation of coordinate systems from say, the (x,y) coordinate system, to some new grid (u,v) on the mapped surface (since the function $f$ is given by $f(u,v) = (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)) \in \mathbb{R}^3 $), the transformation of basis and coordinates can be carried out using the Jacobian matrix of $f$ which I have seen earlier from some basic tensor calculus. And for the the derivative to be full rank means for this Jacobian matrix to be full rank (in this case 2).

Finally they provide some notations for tangent spaces as
$$
T_uU = \{u\} \times \mathbb{R}^2 \\
T_p\mathbb{R}^3 = \{p\} \times \mathbb{R}^3
$$
where $p = f(u)$. As I understand it, the first set represents the set of all directions I can move on the input surface at $u$ such that such that I stay on the surface while the second represents all directions I can move on the output surface at $p$ such that I stay on the surface.

The part I least understand is the following definition,
$$
T_uf = Df\mid_u (T_uU) \subset T_f(u)\mathbb{R}^3
$$
I don't understand why this is defined and how it is different from the definition of tangent space of $U$ at $u$ and tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^3$ at $p$. (Does this set represent all the directions I can move on the input surface such that my counterpart stays on the output surface?)

I highly appreciate your patience on reading my detailed question.